# Claim Based Authentication using WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, claims-based-identity

I am trying to learn Claim Based Authentication. The business services (based on SOAP) will be using this service for authentication.

Can you please give a reference to a simplified implementation in WCF?  Though my actual requirement will be in DataPower, I want to learn the concepts by doing hands on with simplified WCF implementations.

It would be great that article/tutorial/video (with code download) can be implemented as a self hosted service in VS2010.

Note: I don’t have a server to test. Has got my desktop only.

Note: I won’t be able to develop with Windows Identity Foundation since I have only XP.

---

Also, can you please provide a brief comparison of claim based authorization and role based authorization?

REFERENCE:

1. [How to use System.IdentityModel in own client-server application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646395/how-to-use-system-identitymodel-in-own-client-server-application)
2. [Implementing claims-based security (WCF/ASP.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232842/implementing-claims-based-security-wcf-asp-net)

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335707.aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163366.aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd278426.aspx or http://www.leastprivilege.com/TokenBasedAuthenticationForWCFHTTPRESTServicesAuthentication.aspx .....

Answer (score 1):

In claim based authentication as the name indicates, there is a use of claims, which is a sort of identity of a user, claim can be a username, password, email etc. In claim based authentication we get a default implementation of single sign on feature by which we can access application by getting an authentication from an issuer, and providing the credentials once in the beginning.

In role based authentication we have roles which specify that which user is allowed to access which application.Some times with single sign we implement the role based authentication by which if a user provides the credential in the beginning and tries to access an application which he is not authenticated, then he will be barred from doing so.